# How to divide one single image into different link

Tags: jquery, css, image, web

I have a 30(width)px, 130(height)px image in website. I want to create 4 different link from this single image. For example, I want to create from 0 to 32px portion for one link, 33px to 65px portion to another link and like this. Is it possible using from jquery, css or any Idea ?

Comment: Tried to put transparent div, which contains 4 inner clickable divs, on top of the picture?

Comment: another idea is to use single picture as a background for every clickable div with appropriate `{background-position }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
$(function() {
  var img = $("img")
  , parts = img.height() / 4
  , links = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  , regions = $.makeArray(Array(img.height()))
    .map(function(section, key) {
      return key + 1
    })
  , sections = [];

  links.forEach(function(value, key) {
    sections.push(regions.splice(0, Math.floor(Math.round(parts))))
  })

  $("img").on("click", function(e) {
    var res = $.map(sections, function(value, key) {
      return $.inArray(e.clientY, value) !== -1 ? key : null
    })[0];
    console.log("section: " + links[res])
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  background: sienna;
  width: 30px;
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img src="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **map**. Here is an [example](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img/usemap):

```
<map name="bigthings" id="bigthings">
  <area shape="rect" coords="35,4,205,108"
      href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia's_Big_Things"
      alt="Australia's Big Things (on Wikipedia)"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="136,163,255,230"
      href="http://vwkombi.com/"
      alt="The VW Kombi, another Aussie icon"/>
</map>
⋮
<p><img src="giant-prawn.jpg" alt="The Giant Prawn at Ballina"
usemap="#bigthings"/></p>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Does map support any browser ?

Comment: Yes @DipakOjha , even IE [map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_usemap.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just use you picture as a background of container and put `<a>` elements on it:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 85px;
    background: url('http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png') no-repeat;
}

#part1, #part2, #part3 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 85px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="part1" href="http://stackoverflow.com/" />
    <a id="part2" href="http://stackexchange.com" />
    <a id="part3" href="http://github.com"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e2epotyg/1/

Comment: Thanks to you I found what I want. Thanks for your time.